# AWS Amplify | iOS Swift User Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

So i'm getting started with the documentation on AWS Amplify and implementating user authentication into the app, and I was following the documentation exactly but ran into an issue: when implementing the updateUserData function, "UserData" is what it says to have in the docs, but does not exist. I looked at the Swift documentation as well but still have no clue where UserData comes from. Any help would be great

Heres the code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Amplify
import AmplifyPlugins

class Backend {

static let shared = Backend()

static func initialize() -> Backend {
    return .shared
}
private init() {
  // initialize amplify
  do {
    try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
    try Amplify.configure()
    print("Initialized Amplify");
  } catch {
    print("Could not initialize Amplify: \(error)")
  }
}


// MARK: - User Authentication

// signin with Cognito web user interface
public func signIn() {

    _ = Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI(presentationAnchor: UIApplication.shared.windows.first!) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(_):
            print("Sign in succeeded")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Sign in failed \(error)")
        }
    }
}

// signout
public func signOut() {

    _ = Amplify.Auth.signOut() { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success:
            print("Successfully signed out")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Sign out failed with error \(error)")
        }
    }
}

// change our internal state, this triggers an UI update on the main thread
func updateUserData(withSignInStatus status : Bool) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        let userData : UserData = .shared
        userData.isSignedIn = status
        
        
    }
}
```

}

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: You have to make your own

Comment: Are you looking strictly to sign in via web like that or do you care to sign in, in a native way with iOS form?

Comment: i wasn't looking to do anything specifically. this was in the user authentication section of the walkthrough of aws amplify and all i was doing was following the documentation for iOS, as i have never used their service. but to answer ur question, i guess natively with ios form